# Who is the last Spider-Man?

Tags: character, spider-man-into-the-spider-verse

In *Spider-Man: Into the Spider-Verse* during the scene after the credits, we can see a *punisher like* Spider-Man called Miguel (at least in the spanish dub).

Who is he and how its related to the spider-verse?  Is his appearance an indication of his future role in a next movie?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

He is Miguel O'Hara aka [Spider-Man 2099](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spider-Man_2099).

> Miguel O'Hara, a brilliant geneticist living in New York (renamed Nueva York) in the year 2099 A.D. attempts to recreate the abilities of the original Spider-Man in other people and later suffers a related accident that causes half his DNA to be re-written with a spider's genetic code.

End credit scene is elaborated in [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spider-Man:_Into_the_Spider-Verse) too:

> In a post-credits scene, Lyla informs Miguel O'Hara of the crisis and is given his own dimension-hopping technology. He decides to "go back to the beginning" and ends up arguing with [that universe's Spider-Man](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spider-Man_(1967_TV_series)) about who pointed first.

There are plan for a direct sequel and a female centered spin-off but no clear indication about Miguel reveled yet:

From [CBR](https://www.cbr.com/spider-verse-producer-reveals-sequel-spinoff-details/):

> In an interview with Vanity Fair, Pascal confirmed the announced sequel to Spider-Verse is moving forward with Voltron: Legendary Defender showrunner Joaquin Dos Santos directing the film from a script written by David Callaham (Wonder Woman 1984). Pascal then revealed that the sequel would focus on Miles Morales and Earth-65's Gwen Stacy as their multiversal friendship develops into a romantic relationship.
>
> Also in development is a planned spinoff for Spider-Gwen, which Pascal confirms will also introduce Silk and Jessica Drew's incarnation of Spider-Woman. The animated film is being written by Bek Smith with Lauren Montgomery (Batman: Year One) attached to direct.
>
> Additionally, Pascal hints there may be tentative plans for the other heroes introduced in Into the Spider-Verse to star in their own animated spinoffs, including John Mulaney's Spider-Ham. "Of course! You can imagine how much the kids love that character," admitted Pascal.

Answer (score 3):

The last Spider-man is Miguel O'hara also known as Spider-man 2099, a spiderman from the future, we see him together with his AI Lyla.

Miguel O'hara was a normal world class genius and geneticist, but then 50% of his DNA got rewritten to that of a spider and he became Spider-man 2099

You can read more [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spider-Man_2099)

Spider-man 2099 apparently was monitoring the situation we saw and now wants to assemble a team to prevent another crisis in the multiverse. Hopefully, we will get to see this in the sequel.

Comment: thanks for the response but all that, except last sentence, is covered in Ankit's post.